# how to mark avro field deprecated in JSON/avsc?

Tags: java, avro

I was looking for method to mark avro field deprecated in a way that generated Java code (getters, and setters for the field) are marked with `@Deprecated` annotation.

Puting `@Deprecated` into `"doc"` field doesn't work, because generator puts it into `/** javadoc */`.

Answer (score 2):

I have not had success getting the actual `@Deprecated` annotation into the generated java code, but the older style javadoc deprecation kind of works:

```
// schema avdl
record MyRecord {
    /** @deprecated unused */ union { null, int } count;
}
```

results in the generated java code having

```
/** @deprecated unused */
Integer count;
```

And some IDEs recognizes and highlights that (I use Intellij)